# Change variable of all elements inside an array if Set contains it

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, set

I know this is a silly question but I don't know which will be the more performant solution. I have an array of `ListItem`. `ListItem` has a boolean value `isSelected`. I also have `Set<ListItem>`. I want to change that boolean to `true` if array has an element which is also inside Set. How can I achieve this with the best performance?

My Set and Array:

```
var selectedItems = Set<ListItem>()
var array: [ListItem] = []
```

List Item:

```
class ListItem: Codable ,Equatable, Hashable {

    let wrapperType: String
    let kind: String?
    let trackId: Int?
    let artistId: Int?
    let collectionId: Int?
    let artistName, collectionName, trackName: String?
    let trackViewUrl: String?
    let artworkUrl30, artworkUrl60,artworkUrl100: String?
    let releaseDate: String?
    let primaryGenreName: String?
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case wrapperType, kind
        case artistId
        case collectionId
        case trackId
        case artistName, collectionName, trackName
        case trackViewUrl
        case artworkUrl30, artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100, releaseDate, primaryGenreName
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        wrapperType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .wrapperType)
        print(wrapperType)
        kind = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .kind)
        trackId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .trackId)
        collectionId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .collectionId)
        artistId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .artistId)
        artistName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artistName)
        collectionName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .collectionName)
        trackName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .trackName)
        trackViewUrl = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .trackViewUrl)
        artworkUrl30 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artworkUrl30)
        artworkUrl100 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artworkUrl100)
        artworkUrl60 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artworkUrl60)
        releaseDate = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .releaseDate)
        primaryGenreName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .primaryGenreName)

    }

    static func ==(lhs: ListItem, rhs: ListItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.trackName == rhs.trackName
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        if trackId != nil {
            hasher.combine(trackName)
        } else if collectionId != nil {
            //AudioBooks Doesn't have TrackId
            hasher.combine(collectionId)
        } else {
            print("Both TrackId && Collection Id is null")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of `ListItem` to the question? The things I'm interested in are 1) is it a `struct` or a `class`, 2) does `==` and `hash(into:)` exclude the `Bool`

Comment: I added class model

Comment: If all that matters for equality is the `trackName`, your `hash(into:)` function should only `combine` that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these are reference types, if it is guaranteed that there is only one instance of any unique `ListItem`, it would be sufficient to just set `isSelected` to `false` for each item in your `array`, and then set `isSelected` to `true` for each item in your `selectedItems`.

```
array.forEach { $0.isSelected = false }
selectedItems.forEach { $0.isSelected = true }
```

If there can be more than one instance of an item, you are going to have to iterate the items in your `array` and check if the `Set` `contains` them.  Fortunately, `contains` is O(1) for a `Set`:

```
array.forEach { $0.isSelected = selectedItems.contains($0) }
```

---

**Note:**  It is vital that the `hashValue` be equal for `ListItem`s that are equal, or this all breaks down.  Your `hash(into:)` function is currently using more fields than your `==` function, so it is possible to generate a different `hashValue` for equal `ListItem`s.  Fix this to ensure that a proper `hashValue` is generated.